# How to format mat-field with custom css class?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have the code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col s6 m6 ml-0">
            <mat-label>Sistemas</mat-label>
            <mat-select (selectionChange)="changeApplication($event)" formControlName="aplicacoes">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let aplicacao of aplicacoes" [value]="aplicacao.sigla">
                    {{aplicacao.sigla}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
```

If I put a custom class for example: custom-input, how to style it using angular-material? it alredy has the "aparecene" element, but I want use a custom class to make this specific input with border white.

My css that afects all inputs in project:

```
    .mat-form-field {
       margin-top: 15px;

    &:nth-child(2n) {
       padding-left: 30px;
    }

    &.mat-form-field-appearance-outline {
       font-size: 1rem;

       .mat-form-field-outline {
           height: 60px;
           color: #FFF !important;
       }
    }
  }
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the outline appearence without affect any other input component, you can embed your code inside a div container and apply a parent class to override default outline color.

Ex: Put your mat-form-field inside a div container and add a custom class to the div container

It will work.

Comment: No problem bro.